# How would I add a path directory on my php code as when i run my code and upload a file i get an error on line 29

Tags: php, html

I got the following error:

Warning: move_uploaded_file(USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\Picturesgon.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No suchtxt file or directory in C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\Fileupload.php on line 29

Below is part of my codes:

```
<?php
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["users"]["tmp_name"],"USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\\root\Pictures". $_FILES["users"]["name"])) {
echo "Saved as: " . $_FILES["users"]["name"] ; 
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean by this how would I know I'm sorry very new to coding

Comment: According to the error message, your script is located in `C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\ `. Does a folder named `USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\ ` exist _below_ that? So that it is actually `C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\ `? No, of course not, you actually meant to specify `C:\Users\Ali\Desktop\USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\root\ ` as the directory you want the file stored into. Relative paths are relative to the current working directory of the script.

Comment: i have now chnaged it however still getting the error

Comment: im getting the same error it says on line 29

Comment: i have done that ken lee

Comment: yes in the root folder is the PHP file and the pictures fodler

Comment: Im still having trouble can anyone help me please

Comment: im using a usbwebserver

Comment: i cant change the read only files not letting me it goes back to read only

Comment: actually I mean you need to change the php, please refer to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change this line:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["users"]["tmp_name"],"USBWebserver v8.5\8.5\\root\Pictures". $_FILES["users"]["name"]))
```

to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["users"]["tmp_name"],".\Pictures\". $_FILES["users"]["name"]))
```

Comment: Hi , please create a new question. Thanks

Comment: im trying to add a txt file and replace it I have edited the question if u scroll above u will see

Comment: i created a new one

Answer (score 0):

Check your directory permissions:

Commonly used permissions for Cpanel are:

```
Folder permissions: 755

General File permission: 644

Configuration file permissions: 444
```

Comment: how would i do this

Comment: Are you using cpanel?

Comment: no im using notepad++ and using usbwebserver